# Complex integral $\int_{1-i}^{1+i}|z|^2 dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration

Question: Find $\int_{C}|z|^2 dz$, where $C$ is the line segment from $1-i$ to $1+i$.

My attempt: We substitute $z(t) = 1 + it$ for $-1\leq t\leq1$ with $dz/dt = i$.

The integrand becomes $|z(t)|^2 = 1 + t^2$. So finally

$$ \int_{C}^{} |z|^2 dz = \int_{-1}^{1} (1 + t^2)i dt = \left.(t + t^3/3)i\right|_{-1}^{1} = 8i/3$$

But the answer key says $8/3$. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Why do you assume that there's something wrong with that answer?

Comment: Your answer is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Here's Mathematica doing the same thing by way of "proof". Your working is fine. [image]

Comment: Ok thanks for confirming.  I'll submit to the publisher.  The book is Complex Analysis Zill and Shananhan in case anyone is tripping on the same problem.